# Export pie chart form html to excel file

Tags: javascript, export, pie-chart

I want to export pie chart from html to excel file by javascript. But i can't find a library do it. 
Please, see me how can do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Think, if it is possible using JS.

Comment: This is something for the backend. JS have very limited access to the filesystem if any.

Comment: The pie chart you are seeing is a bmp/jpg/png image.  You can't really create an Excel file from an image.

Answer (score 0):

I googled it and found another [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742422/generate-office-open-xml-excel-file-from-javascript) about this exact problem. Obviously it seems possible that you actually may create an excel file from javascript. This is probably much harder then just creating it from the backend. But anyways, if you want to try and and do it here is the link to github-page by Ed Spencer: https://github.com/edspencer/Ext.ux.Exporter

Comment: Thanks cubsink. But when I used it, the format file excel not exactly with starnd format. MS Office 2012 don't open this file.