# Can we manage MS Word formats using HTML?

Tags: html, ms-word

I am going to generate a word document according to html page. I need some formatting like page break and customize heading of the document such as .can i achieve them using html?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would go about customizing the header using HTML. In general, what you're planning on doing is probably a bad idea. I would look at libraries that let you generate regular `.docx` files (the Word XML format).

With that said, I think you can get your page breaks with:

```
<br clear="all" style="mso-special-character:line-break; page-break-before:always" />
```

Comment: yes thanks it is one of the commands i wanted, it works, Is there any other html phrases we can use to customize msword

Comment: I'm not sure where you will find a good list, but you may want to do things like change the page margins, etc. There's an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7341/Dynamically-generate-a-MS-Word-document-using-HTML) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Pure HTML would be hard. But keep in mind the current Word-Dokument-Format is OPENXML (or sort of Microsoftish). 
I bet there are libraries that could help you assemble or compile word doxs with javascript.

[Generate office open XML excel file from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742422/generate-office-open-xml-excel-file-from-javascript)

http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2012/08/02/working-with-open-xml-documents-using-javascript.aspx

http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/open-xml-and-javascript.aspx

as far as I know a page-break in OpenXml could be acomplished like this...

```
    <w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:br w:type="page" />
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Select the page in the browser and use cut&pase. Word does recognize HTML in the clipboard and then tries its best to preserve the formatting.

If you need something more complex, you need to write a program that converts HTML to the OOXML format.

Comment: no here I m going to customize JIRA report generation format according to my company report format. Then generation is done by a java class which i dont have the permission to change. So i have to give html codes which can generate msword commands at the runtime.